# Wordpress ajax detect template from absolute URL

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, url-rewriting

Is it possible to get template file from full url in Wordpress? What I want is load over ajax page template part to my html page. I have standard nav_menu with full link. I know, that it is possible over hiding `get_header` and `get_footer` in the request in template file (over `!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])`), but is there a better solution?

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_template', 'super_ajax_template' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_template', 'super_ajax_template' );
function super_ajax_template() {

    // parse_str($_POST['form'], $data);

    $data['slug'] = 'http://test.com/page/page/';

    global $wp_rewrite;

    /* DETECT template from full url (page.php etc..) */

    if ( !locate_template($filename . '.php'))
        wp_send_json_error( __('Not found.', 'domain') );

    ob_start();
    get_template_part($filename);
    $template = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    if ( !empty($template) ) {
        wp_send_json_success( array( 'content' => $template ) );
    }

}
```

Comment: now I found wordpress function url_to_postid()

Comment: almost solution http://betterwp.net/wordpress-tips/url_to_postid-for-custom-post-types/